# Taxonomies image

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin, admin, uploads, images

I'm currently creating a theme and I would like to associate an image to one of my taxonomies.

I'm already able to add some fields and I now want to add a file input which'll be handle by Wordpress upload function.

So, 2 questions :
- Is it possible to add an enctype to the taxonomy form ?
- Is it possible to use the Wordpress upload function at this point ?

Thanks for your answers.

Cyril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Fields built the perfect plugin for this:

http://wordpress.mfields.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/

Comment: Not perfect yet, some features are missing like fetching an image for a not queried taxonomy, but I'll do with that :)